# Insert 5 keywords randomly into only a section of an HTML Table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am considerably new to JavaScript. I have an 8 x 8 HTML table as a board for a game that is dynamically created in the JS file like this:

```
function drawBoard(rows, cols){
   var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
   grid.className = 'grid';
   for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
       var row = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
       for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
            var cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
       }    
    }
    return grid;
}
document.body.appendChild(drawBoard(ROW, COL));
```

The board displays successfully when I load the page. I need to insert 5 keywords randomly on 5 cells. These cells cannot be along the outside border of squares (i.e., cannot be in the first or last row or column). I have the 5 keywords as an array in my javascript file. How can I randomly pick 5 cells on the table excluding the first or last row or column and insert these keywords on them everytime I draw the board? I tried cell.innerHTML = "keyword" but ended up inserting only one of the keywords on every single cell on the table. Did a thorough search online without any luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// I'm assuming ROW, COL and keywords are declared somewhere in your code
const ROW = 8;
const COL = 8;
const keywords = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
// --- your code, no changes
function drawBoard(rows, cols, keywords) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        var row = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
// save the table in a variable
const grd = document.body.appendChild(drawBoard(ROW, COL));
//--- NEW CODE STARTS HERE
const shuffle = array => {
    const shuffled = [];
    while (array.length) {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
        shuffled.push(array.splice(index, 1).pop());
    }
    return shuffled;
};

const filtered = Array.from(grd.querySelectorAll('td'))
    .filter(({cellIndex, parentElement: {rowIndex}}) => rowIndex && rowIndex < ROW - 1 && cellIndex && cellIndex < COL - 1);

const shuffled = shuffle(filtered);

const sliced = filtered.slice(0, keywords.length);

sliced.forEach((cell, index) => cell.innerHTML = keywords[index]);
```

```html
<table id="grid"></table>
```

`filtered` is all the cells not on the border

`shuffled` array is simply all the filtered cells shuffled using the shuffle function

`sliced` array is the first `n` cells from the shuffled array, where `n` is the number of keywords

then it's a simple matter of adding the keywords

---

To explain the filter function:

```
({cellIndex, parentElement: {rowIndex}}) => 
    rowIndex && rowIndex < ROW - 1 && cellIndex && cellIndex < COL - 1;
```

this is ES6 way of performing

```
function(cell) {
    var cellIndex = cell.cellIndex;
    var parentElement = cell.parentElement;
    var rowIndex = parentElement.rowIndex;
    return rowIndex && rowIndex < ROW - 1 && cellIndex && cellIndex < COL - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great approach as well. I tried upvoting but my reputation does not seem to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all extract 5 random cells in the 64 - 28 available. We have a 6x6 square available then.

```
//We keep an array to store cells for keywords
var keyCells = [];

//A function to check if we already choosed a cell
function checkChoosed( x, y ) {

    if( keyCells.length > 0 ) {
        for( var j = 0; j < keyCells.length; j++ ) {

            if( ( keyCells[ j ].x == x ) && ( keyCells[ j ].y == y ) ) return 1;

        }

    }

    return 0;

}

//Pick random coordinates (in 6x6 square) for cells
function randomCells() {

    var choosed = 0;

    while( choosed < 5 ) {

        var x = Math.round( Math.random() * 5 ) + 1; //Math.random returns a number between 0 and 0.99, so * 5 to get from 0 to 4.95, + 1 because we skip first row and column of the grid
        var y = Math.round( Math.random() * 5 ) + 1;

        if( !checkChoosed( x, y ) ) {

            keyCells.push( { x: x, y: y } );
            choosed++;

        }

    }

}

//Now we draw the table and access it for keywords
function drawBoard(rows, cols) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for ( var r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        var row = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for ( var c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {
             var cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        }    
    }

    randomCells();

    var trs = document.getElementById('grid').children;

    for( var i = 0; i < keyCells.length; i++ ) {

        var currX = keyCells[ i ].x;
        var currY = keyCells[ i ].y;

        //Here I used the ":nth-child" CSS selector to access "tr" (our Y) and then "td" (our X)

        var currRow = trs[ currY ].children;
        currRow[ currX ].innerHTML = /* your keyword here */

    }

    return grid;

}
```

Comment: why are you using jquery when the question doesn't?

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem and makes me realize that I could look at it as a smaller grid inside the larger one.